# Java Calendar wrong time for PST time zone?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

Playing around with `Calendar` and `TimeZone` I encountered following strange behaviour.

```
Calendar pstCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println("H: "+ pstCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
```

At the moment of writing this post, PST time according to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst is 1:39am. The code shown above however produces output "**H: 2**"

**Why 2 instead of 1 ?**
Closer look at the Calendar instance explains the number 2: **dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true**

But what I understood so far, PST stands for Pacific Standard Time, which means time without daylight saving.

Why is Java treating **PST** this way and **is it right or is it a BUG** ? Btw this problem isn't here for **EST** - here it corresponds with http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est.

I saw this happening for Oracle JDK 1.8.0_60 and OpenJDK 1.8.0_60 as well.

Comment: A time *zone* is a geographical concept, it doesn't imply that daylight rules apply or not. `PST` or `EST` are unofficial acronyms whose meanings change from country to country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> **Three-letter time zone IDs**
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, **their use is deprecated** because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

Specifically, Java may have decided that "PST" was equivalent to "America/Los_Angeles" in the past, which would mean that alternated between PST and PDT for daylight saving time.  They may have decided differently about "EST" for whatever reason.

As a time zone identifier, abbreviations are no good.  You will still find them in common use in *display* values, including the abbreviations on [timeanddate.com](http://timeanddate.com).  But that doesn't mean they are interpreted in the same way by Java.

If you really want to get technical about why "EST" and "PST" are treated differently with regard to daylight saving time when interpreted by Java as time zone IDs, consider that "EST", "MST", and "HST" [are still in the tzdb source data](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/7a39f82a5e755a669d6fab595b5d88788508788b/northamerica#L149-L151) as fixed offset time zones for POSIX backward compatibility reasons.  "PST" and "CST" are no longer listed in the tzdb, so Java interprets them through some other hard-coded mapping for their own backwards compatibility with Java 1.1.

Comment: You could illustrate this by asking what [PST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PST) means? Is it Pakistan, Pacific or Philipines Standard Time? What is [EST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST#Time)? Is it the Australian Eastern Standard Time, Egypt Standard Time, East Europe Summer time?

Comment: Thanks for exhausting explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Kousalik, first the short-name is not a good way to identify a time-zone, because it's not unique; Moreover if you call useDaylightTime() on EST timezone object then it will return false whereas when you call useDaylightTime() on PST timezone object then it returns true.
From this its assured that JDK considers the two time zone differently.

```
    TimeZone esttz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
    System.out.println(esttz.getDisplayName() + " "+esttz.useDaylightTime());

    TimeZone psttz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
    System.out.println(psttz.getDisplayName() + " "+psttz.useDaylightTime());
```

Returns -

Eastern Standard Time false

Pacific Standard Time true

Comment: Yes, as I stated in the question... But that doesn't explain why PST in java uses daylightTime (eg behaves like PDT) and EST does not? EST and PST are zones without daylight saving according to http://www.timeanddate.com/. I would at least expect both behaving the same way.

Comment: PDT and EST are *not* timezones, they are convenience acronyms that Java, .NET or Windows decided to attach to specific timezones. Anyone who needs to work with different timezones either uses explicit offsets or the rules defined in IANA's tzdb