# TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST") vs TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, jodatime, java-time

I'm Using Java 8,

Earlier in our code, We were using  `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));` to convert to US Pacific which was failed(not throwing any errors but converted to default timezone) due to PDT is not a valid ZoneId.

So I look for `setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));` which is also not available in the `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` values.

Finally I end up with using `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));`

Now, One of our friends using `setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));` to convert to us-pacific timezone and the conversion is happening properly..

Question is,

What is the difference between `TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");` and `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");`

Which one is better to use ?

Comment: I recommend you neither use `SimpleDateFormat` nor `TimeZone`. Both classes are poorly designed and long outdated (the former in particular notoriously troublesome). Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), built into your Java 8 (and later).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for [Error Prone's ThreeLetterTimeZoneID check](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ThreeLetterTimeZoneID):

> According to the Javadoc of `java.util.TimeZone`:
>
> > For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as “PST”, “CTT”, “AST”) are also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, “CST” could be U.S. “Central Standard Time” and “China Standard Time”), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.
>
> Aside from the ambiguity between timezones, there is inconsistency in
>   the observance of Daylight Savings Time for the returned time zone,
>   meaning the TimeZone obtained may not be what you expect. Examples
>   include:
>
> `DateTime.getTimeZone("PST")` does observe daylight savings time;
>   however, the identifier implies that it is Pacific Standard Time, i.e.
>   daylight savings time is not observed. `DateTime.getTimeZone("EST")`
>   (and `"MST"` and `"HST"`) do not observe daylight savings time. However,
>   this is inconsistent with PST (and others), so you may believe that
>   daylight savings time will be observed.

So: Use the full `America/Los_Angeles` format to minimize the ambiguity in the code.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Java 8 Timezone documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html), `PST` use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones.
That's why is preferred to use `America/Los_Angeles`

Answer (score 2):

Better is to use "America/Los_Angeles" as this is valid time zone according to TZ Database. See this [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them..

See this [LINK](http://ase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

You can also see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627139/java-calendar-wrong-time-for-pst-time-zone) SO post that shows problem with using 3 letter timezone ID.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Don’t use PST. Use America/Los_Angeles. Also don’t use the `TimeZone` class. Use `ZoneId`.

- PST may mean Pitcairn Standard Time, Pacific Standard Time or Philippine Standard Time.
- If you take PST to mean Pacific Standard Time, that is not a time zone since all of the places that use it as their standard time are currently and for most of the year on Pacific Daylight Time instead.
- While the outdated `TimeZone` class interprets PST the same as America/Los_Angeles, as others have long said, the three letter abbreviations are deprecated. Should `TimeZone` one day (however unlikely) cease to recognize PST, it will instead give you GMT, which is certainly not what you want.

### java.time

The `TimeZone` class was poorly designed and sometimes confusing, and is fortunately long outdated, replaced by `ZoneId` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, 5 years ago.

A short code example to help you get started using the modern API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL)
            .withLocale(Locale.US);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

> Friday, April 12, 2019 at 8:14:09 AM Pacific Daylight Time

One advantage of `ZoneId` is it doesn’t readily let you use `PST` as a time zone: `ZoneId.of("PST")` throws a `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: PST` (there is a workaround if you insist, but as we have said, you shouldn’t).

### Links

- [Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)
- [PST – Pacific Standard Time / Pacific Time (Standard Time)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/pst)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.